# Do you have to config 2 mappers for bi-directional mapping with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

For every POCO do you need to configure both the source and destinations each way?

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {

    cfg.CreateMap<Customer, ServiceModel.Types.InRule.Customer>();
    cfg.CreateMap<ServiceModel.Types.InRule.Customer, Customer>();

});
```

I thought I heard something about a ReverseMap somewhere and wondered if it meant you only needed to configure one way, the other would be inferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ReverseMap() would do the work.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Customer, ServiceModel.Types.InRule.Customer>().ReverseMap();  
});
```

Comment: Note that `ReverseMap()` only handles simple mappings where all the names are the same and all properties are mapped.

Comment: If you as well want to map the complex objects, then they should be mapped above it. All dependencies must be mapped before mapping the main one. This will solve the complex object mapping problem as well.